# Google Charts - Organisation Chart appears broken

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization

Here's what I mean. Those protruding horizontal lines aren't supposed to be there.

[image: Broken org chart]

I'm using [vue-google-charts](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts#usage) and following the implementation stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704172/how-to-create-an-organization-chart-using-vue-google-charts).

Any idea about how I can fix this? It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Check the default style of the table/tr/td.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check the default style of the table/tr/td